# if statement in the save props > return field?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

is it possible to write a if statement in the return() from the save props in react?

Because when i write down a if statement i only see the code at the front-end.

So the following is happening:

I created a Selectcontrol:

```js
<SelectControl

              label={ __( 'Press ctrl to multiple stars:' ) }
              value={ testimonial.selectcontrol } // e.g: value = [ 'a', 'c' ]
              onChange={ (value) => handleTestimonialChange('selectcontrol', value, index ) }
              options={ [
                  { value: null, label: 'Select a Star', disabled: false },
                  { value: 'star' ,  label: 'Add 1 star' },
                  { value: 'star2', label: 'Add 2 stars' },
                  { value: 'star3', label: 'Add 3 stars' },
                  { value: 'star4', label: 'Add 4 stars' },
                  { value: 'star5', label: 'Add 5 stars' },
              ] }
            />
```

I render it with the following code to have stars in the back-end:

```js
selectcontrolDisplay = props.attributes.testimonial.map( ( testimonial, index ) => {
          if (testimonial.selectcontrol == 'star') {
            return  (testimonial.selectcontrol == 'star') ? <span><i className="fas fa-star checked"></i></span> : testimonial.selectcontrol;
          } else if (testimonial.selectcontrol == 'star2') {
            return  (testimonial.selectcontrol == 'star2') ? <span><i className="fas fa-star checked"></i><i className="fas fa-star checked"></i></span> : testimonial.selectcontrol;
          } else if (testimonial.selectcontrol == 'star3') {
            return  (testimonial.selectcontrol == 'star3') ? <span><i className="fas fa-star checked"></i><i className="fas fa-star checked"></i><i className="fas fa-star checked"></i></span> : testimonial.selectcontrol;
          } else if (testimonial.selectcontrol == 'star4') {
            return  (testimonial.selectcontrol == 'star4') ? <span><i className="fas fa-star checked"></i><i className="fas fa-star checked"></i><i className="fas fa-star checked"></i><i className="fas fa-star checked"></i></span>: testimonial.selectcontrol;
          } else if (testimonial.selectcontrol == 'star5') {
            return  (testimonial.selectcontrol == 'star5') ? <span><i className="fas fa-star checked"></i><i className="fas fa-star checked"></i><i className="fas fa-star checked"></i><i className="fas fa-star checked"></i><i className="fas fa-star checked"></i></span> : testimonial.selectcontrol;
          }
        } );
```

In the editor part i have the following part:

```js
{selectcontrolDisplay && selectcontrolDisplay.map((selectcontrolValue, i) =>
                  <div className="wp-block-cgb-block-project-drie-testimonial-ratings">
                    <div className="wp-block-cgb-block-project-drie-testimonial-rating">
                      <h2>Rating</h2>
                      {selectcontrolValue}
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  )}
```

So above is working correctly, but the hardest part for me is to get the result at the front-end.

So i thought i could make it work with a if statement. But i only see the code at the front-end and not the result with only stars. Could some on give me advice how to make this work?

```js
save: ( props ) => {
const {attributes: { selectcontrol } } = props;

return (

html code.....

if (selectcontrol == 'star') {
                      <span><i className="fas fa-star checked"></i></span>
                    } else if (selectcontrol == 'star2') {
                      <span><i className="fas fa-star checked"></i><i className="fas fa-star checked"></i></span>
                    } else if (selectcontrol == 'star3') {
                      <span><i className="fas fa-star checked"></i><i className="fas fa-star checked"></i><i className="fas fa-star checked"></i></span>
                    } else if (selectcontrol == 'star4') {
                      <span><i className="fas fa-star checked"></i><i className="fas fa-star checked"></i><i className="fas fa-star checked"></i><i className="fas fa-star checked"></i></span>
                    } else if (selectcontrol == 'star5') {
                      <span><i className="fas fa-star checked"></i><i className="fas fa-star checked"></i><i className="fas fa-star checked"></i><i className="fas fa-star checked"></i><i className="fas fa-star checked"></i></span>
                    }

)

}
```

For a better overview:

```js
save: ( props ) => {
    const {attributes: { title } } = props;
    const {attributes: { subtitle } } = props;
    const {attributes: { media} } = props;
    const {attributes: { testimonial } } = props;
    const {attributes: { selectcontrol } } = props;

  
    return (
      <section className="testimonial">
        <Helmet>
          <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/kenwheeler/slick@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>
        </Helmet>
        <div className="container testimonial__container">
          <div className="row testimonial__row">
            <div className="testimonial__info">
              <div className="testimonial__subtext">
                <span>{ subtitle }</span>
              </div>
              <div className="testimonial__title">
                <h2>{ title }</h2>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="items testimonial__testimonials">
              {testimonial.map((field, i) => (
              <div className="testimonial__testimonial">
                <div className="testimonial__card" key={ i }>
                  <div className="testimonial__image">
                    <img src={field.media.url} />
                  </div>
                  <div className="testimonial__review">
                    <p>{field.testimonial}</p>
                  </div>
                    if (selectcontrol == 'star') {
                      <span><i className="fas fa-star checked"></i></span>
                    } else if (selectcontrol == 'star2') {
                      <span><i className="fas fa-star checked"></i><i className="fas fa-star checked"></i></span>
                    } else if (selectcontrol == 'star3') {
                      <span><i className="fas fa-star checked"></i><i className="fas fa-star checked"></i><i className="fas fa-star checked"></i></span>
                    } else if (selectcontrol == 'star4') {
                      <span><i className="fas fa-star checked"></i><i className="fas fa-star checked"></i><i className="fas fa-star checked"></i><i className="fas fa-star checked"></i></span>
                    } else if (selectcontrol == 'star5') {
                      <span><i className="fas fa-star checked"></i><i className="fas fa-star checked"></i><i className="fas fa-star checked"></i><i className="fas fa-star checked"></i><i className="fas fa-star checked"></i></span>
                    }
                  <div className="testimonial__stars">
                    <span>{testimonial.selectcontrol}</span>

                  </div>
                  <div className="testimonial__author">
                    <div className="testimonial__name">
                      <span>{ field.author }</span>
                    </div>
                    <div className="testimonial__function">
                      <span>{ field.position }</span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              ))}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    );
    },
```

Comment: `if (testimonial.selectcontrol == 'star') { return  (testimonial.selectcontrol == 'star') ? <span><i className="fas fa-star checked"></i></span> : testimonial.selectcontrol; }` you know the ternary operator is redundant, right? since `testimonial.selectcontrol == 'star'` is true in the `if` test, it'll still be true on the next line

Comment: Could that be a reason why the code is showing at the front-end? I haven't tested it out yet, or it's working. Because i only see the code from the if statement.

Comment: sorry, absolutely no idea what your problem even is, just noticed the redundant code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your code, you've tried really hard to get the right markup to save your stars by using `if/if else` statements. You can have [conditional rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html) statements, but for your code/objective of saving the right markup for the stars may I suggest another way..

In the Editor, you have a `<SelectControl/>` for setting a "star rating", so we want to save the *value* of the star rating in the block attributes. So lets assume we have defined "starRating" in the blocks attributes, eg:

**block.json**

```
{
    ...
    "attributes": {
        "starRating": {
            "type": "string",
            "default": "1"
        }
    }
}
```

*I've set a default of **1** so there is no need for a null option on the `<SelectControl/>`*

There is alot going on in your `Edit()` function to render your beautiful star icons, so I will focus on the bare minimum required in the `<SelectControl/>`. By using a number, we now can use map and easily generate the required options labels & values:

**edit.js**

```
import { __ } from '@wordpress/i18n';
import { useBlockProps } from '@wordpress/block-editor';
import { SelectControl } from '@wordpress/components';

export default function Edit({ attributes, setAttributes }) {
const { starRating } = attributes;

    const STARS = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

    return (
        <div {...useBlockProps()}> 
            <SelectControl
                label={__('Set Star Rating')}
                value={starRating}
                options={STARS.map((number) => {
                    let label = '*'.repeat(number); // simple trick for number of stars
                     return {
                         label: label,
                         value: number
                     }
                })}
                onChange={(value) => setAttributes({ starRating: value })} />
        </div>
    );
}
```

Next, in `save()` the correct markup can be generated using the saved value of "starRating" with the benefit of avoiding `if` `if/else` statements altogether:

**save.js**

```
import { useBlockProps } from '@wordpress/block-editor';
export default function save({ attributes }) {
    const { starRating } = attributes;

    return (
        <div {...useBlockProps.save()}>
            <span>
                {[...Array(parseInt(starRating))].map((item, index) =>
                    <i key={index} className="fas fa-star checked"></i>
                )}
            </span>
        </div>
    );
}
```

*Note: "key" is required by react - it will not appear in the saved content or frontend.*

**Suggestions:** Given all the content in your block, you may soon find managing both `edit()` and `save()` consistency to be challenging.  Try to focus on the specific feature your block does, in your case the "star rating". With all the other parts, eg testimonial title, testimonial subtext etc, I'd suggest creating a [reusable block](https://wordpress.com/support/wordpress-editor/blocks/reusable-block/) or [block/post template](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/block-api/block-templates/) so you can easily change the layout/formatting/order of block/class names in the future. Updating/migrating blocks can be quite challenging if you need to change what is saved - if you can avoid having to do this, future you will thank you!

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I got it work with the advice you gave me! I am really happy about it! I will have a look about your suggestions. Working with the block/post template will make it easyer by the looks of it. Awesome! thank you for your time!

Comment: @dennis No worries, really happy to hear you were able to get it working! Yes, reusable blocks and/or post templates will make things easier in the long run..